# generic grid framework implementation

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, architecture, software-design

I'm working on a generic grid framework to use in my video games, where a grid is defined by a interface `IGrid <T>`, T being constrained to a `GridCell`. the grid has to implement a `Generate` method which instantiates the cells but then a `GridPositioniningRule` takes care of how each cell would be positioned within the grid. This is where i'm having trouble, I'm working on a `RectGrid2D` and i've got a rule `BasicPositionRule` which should only be used with `RectGrid2D` since it needs to know the grids columns + rows but I can't figure out how to constrain my rule to a `RectGrid` nicely.

here's my code base so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IGrid<T> where T : GridCell
{

    Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T> grid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// populates the grid with cell type t + a shiny callback to handle each cell after instantiation
    /// </summary>
    void Generate(T t, IGridPositionRule<T, IGrid<T>> positionRule, System.Action<int, int, T> callback);


    /// <summary>
    /// returns the cell at given grid coordinate
    /// </summary>
    T Fetch(GridCoordinate coord);
}

public partial class RectGrid2D <T> : MonoBehaviour, IGrid<T> where T : GridCell
{
    public int rows;
    public int columns;

   public Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T> grid { get; set; }

    public void Generate(T t, IGridPositionRule<T, IGrid<T>> positionRule, Action<int, int, T> callback)
    {
        grid = new Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T>();
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++)
            {
                var coord = new GridCoordinate(x, y);
                var cell = GameObject.Instantiate(t);
                grid.Add(coord, cell);

                positionRule.PositionCell(cell, this, x, y);

                System.Action<int, int, T> _callback = callback;
                if (_callback != null)
                {
                    _callback(x, y, cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the cell at given grid coordinate
    /// </summary>
    public T Fetch(GridCoordinate coord)
    {
        return grid[coord];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a grid cell given T
    /// </summary>
    public GridCoordinate CoordinateFromCell(T cell)
    {
        return grid.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == cell).Key;
    }
}

public struct GridCoordinate 
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public GridCoordinate (int _x, int _y)
    {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
    }
}

public class GridCell : MonoBehaviour 
{
}

public interface IGridPositionRule <T, U> where T : GridCell where U : IGrid <T>
{
    void PositionCell(T cell, U grid, int x, int y);
}

public class BasicPositionRule : IGridPositionRule<GridCell, RectGrid2D<GridCell>>
{
    public void PositionCell(GridCell cell, RectGrid2D<GridCell> grid, int x, int y)
    {
        // do math to position cells for rect grid type pattern 
    }
}

public partial class GridExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GridCell gridCell; // prefab

    private void Awake()
    {
        RectGrid2D<GridCell> grid = GetComponent<RectGrid2D<GridCell>>();
        grid.Generate(gridCell, new BasicPositionRule(), (x, y, cell) => // ERROR HERE
        {
            // do something with grid cell
        });
    }
}
```

now this throws a error `"Argument #2 cannot convert BasicPositionRule expression to type IGridPositionRule<GridCell,IGrid<GridCell>>"`

but I want my `BasicPositionRule` to to be exclusive to a `RectGrid2D` but that throws a error: "Argument `#2' cannot convert`BasicPositionRule' expression to type `IGridPositionRule>'"

the error can be fixes by not constraining the `BasicPositionRule` to `RectGrid2D`
like:

```
public class BasicPositionRule : IGridPositionRule<GridCell, IGrid<GridCell>>
{
    public void PositionCell(GridCell cell, IGrid<GridCell> grid, int x, int y)
    {
        // do math to position cells for rect grid type pattern 
    }
}
```

but I'm really trying to figure out how to constrain a positioning rule to a specific grid type.

Comment: Where is the error *cannot convert BasicPositionRule expression to type SM.Grid.IGridPositionRule* thrown? And what paramter of which method did you changed to fix it?

Comment: @zwcloud error is at line 28 of GridExample, and changing both RectGrid2D definitions to IGrid in BasicPositionRule fixes the error

Comment: Please edit the code and comment where is *line 28*...

Comment: @zwcloud I'm not really sure how to do that on here? but line 28 refers to the Generate method on the grid instance in GridExample, so: grid.Generate(gridCell, new BasicPositionRule(), (x, y, cell) =>

Comment: It's better to provide a compilable code. I have tried to make your code work in Unity3D but failed. I'm sorry but your description is still not clear while the code contains too many types. See [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @zwcloud I've edited my post to contain any extra classes involved, you should be able to replicate everything in unity and get to the same state as I.

Comment: What is SpriteCell? Also, your "fix" to `BasicPositionRule` seems exacly the same as the problematic `BasicPositionRule` (except for the difference between SpriteCell and GridCell, that you never explain)

Comment: @dogiordano my bad, SpriteCell was just a class that inherited GridCell, I've removed all references to it since it doesn't actually have any relation to what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: But still the problematic and fixed `BasicPositionRule` are identical so I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you clarify that a bit more?

Comment: @dogiordano you're right, I've edited my fixed 'BasicPositionRule', so I want to constrain my BasicPositionRule to be exclusively used with a RectGrid2D, but that was my issue, i'd get the error mentioned above, but the error can be fixed by removing the constraint and making the BasicPositionRule contained to IGrid<T> but then the rule doesn't have have access to the RectGrids columns + rows which is what i'm trying to achieve. Hope that clarifies things

Comment: I need a couple more informations before I can answer. You created an `IGridPositionRule` to abstract away positioning of cells on a grid. So, to me, it looks like it should be the implementation of this interface to define a particular type of grid (rectangular vs other types). But then you create a `RectGrid` and whoever calls `Generate` is allowed to pass in any kind of positioning-rule. You want `BasicPositionRule` to only be used with `RectGrid` but is the opposite also true? Is the positioning-rule what really defines the shape of the grid?

Comment: @dogiordano yes, the positioning rule is what defines the shape of the grid, the grid acts more like a data structure, it's handles the relationship between cells without caring about the positioning of them, thats defined by the positioning rule

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138395/discussion-between-dogiordano-and-scott).

Answer (score 1):

How about letting `RectGrid2D` implement both `IGrid` and `IGridPositionRule`?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IGrid<T> where T : GridCell
{
    Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T> grid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// populates the grid with cell type t + a shiny callback to handle each cell after instantiation
    /// </summary>
    void Generate(T t, System.Action<int, int, T> callback);

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the cell at given grid coordinate
    /// </summary>
    T Fetch(GridCoordinate coord);
}

public partial class RectGrid2D<T> : MonoBehaviour, IGrid<T>, IGridPositionRule<T> where T : GridCell
{
    public int rows;
    public int columns;

   public Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T> grid { get; set; }

    public void Generate(T t, Action<int, int, T> callback)
    {
        grid = new Dictionary<GridCoordinate, T>();
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++)
            {
                var coord = new GridCoordinate(x, y);
                var cell = GameObject.Instantiate(t);
                grid.Add(coord, cell);

                PositionCell(cell, x, y);

                System.Action<int, int, T> _callback = callback;
                if (_callback != null)
                {
                    _callback(x, y, cell);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// returns the cell at given grid coordinate
    /// </summary>
    public T Fetch(GridCoordinate coord)
    {
        return grid[coord];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a grid cell given T
    /// </summary>
    public GridCoordinate CoordinateFromCell(T cell)
    {
        return grid.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == cell).Key;
    }

    public void PositionCell(T cell, int x, int y)
    {
        //define your position rule
    }
}

public struct GridCoordinate 
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public GridCoordinate (int _x, int _y)
    {
        this.x = _x;
        this.y = _y;
    }
}

public class GridCell : MonoBehaviour 
{
}

public interface IGridPositionRule <T> where T : GridCell
{
    void PositionCell(T cell, int x, int y);
}

public partial class GridExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GridCell gridCell; // prefab

    private void Awake()
    {
        RectGrid2D<GridCell> grid = GetComponent<RectGrid2D<GridCell>>();
        grid.Generate(gridCell, (x, y, cell) =>
        {
            // do something with grid cell
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to figure out a way to separate the build rule from the grid, the build rule doesn't need to exist if it's being done within the grid class.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you said you want a way to separate the build rule from the grid class. But since you only want certain rules to only be used from certain grids, you are actually coupling them. Also, you are creating a class `RectGrid2D` for the specific case a rectangular positioning-rule is used. So you are actually making the positioning to depend on the grid and not only on some external rule.

So I see two possibilities: either grids and positioning rules should be completely decoupled or completely coupled.

In the first case, the `RectGrid2D` class is probably redundant: only a base `Grid` class should exist and use an external positioning-rule. The rule should contain everything specific to the geometry (layout, finding neighbours, etc)

In the second case getting you don't need the positioning rule and you can put everything inside specific grid classes, like so:

```
public class GridCell : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public abstract class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void Generate(GridCell prefab);
    public abstract GridCell GetAt(int x, int y);
    public abstract List<GridCell> GetNeighboursOf(GridCell cell, List<GridCell> result);
}

public class RectGrid : Grid
{
    public int rows;
    public int columns;
    public RectGrid(int r, int c)
    {
        rows = r;
        columns = c;
    }
    public override GridCell GetAt(int x, int y) { return null; }

    public override List<GridCell> GetNeighboursOf(GridCell cell, List<GridCell> result)
    {
        // You can change this in an hex grid
        result.Add(GetAt(cell.x + 1, cell.y));
        result.Add(GetAt(cell.x - 1, cell.y));
        result.Add(GetAt(cell.x, cell.y + 1));
        result.Add(GetAt(cell.x, cell.y - 1));
        return result;
    }
    // RectGrid knows how to layout its cells
    public override void Generate(GridCell prefab)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                // Instantiate prefab
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class GridExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GridCell gridCell; // prefab

    private void Awake()
    {
        RectGrid grid = GetComponent<RectGrid>();
        grid.Generate(gridCell);
    }
}
```